# Calculate offset when attaching a game object to edge of another game object

Tags: unity, 2d, vector

I am doing a sort of hook, where whenever the hook collides with something, it retracts itself and pulls the the object it collided with back along with it.

[image: Hook example]

But the objects the hook can collide with are not the same sizes, so I can't just create a fixed spawn point and assign that transform to the hooked game object, as some of them would clip the hook and others would be too far away.

So I need to find out what the offset should be, based on the size of the hooked game objects, but I don't know how to calculate it. Especially since the hook can also be rotated, so just offsetting on the y axis for example is not enough, since it might also need to be offset on the x-axis - Pic explaining it:

[image: Diagram]

So any advice on how to calculate the offset (I have my bounds.size to use), and then apply it correctly on both the X and Y axis so the attached game object doesn't clip my hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to calculate the correct offset on both the x and y axis.
It was due to my lack of knowledge on vectors..

I had to find the magnitude of the hooked game object and then multiply that by half (so I have half the size of the gameobject) and store that in a var called offsetDistance.

Then I multiply my position with -offsetDistance and then it works. Code used to solve it:

```
        float offsetDistance = spriteRenderer.bounds.size.magnitude * .5f;

        Vector3 hookPos = hook.transform.position;
        Vector3 hookDirection = hook.transform.up;

        Vector3 spawnPos = hookPos + hookDirection * -offsetDistance;
        transform.position = new Vector2(spawnPos.x, spawnPos.y);
```